# What is the difference between doing a regression with a dataframe and ndarray?

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, numpy-ndarray

I would like to know why would I need to convert my dataframe to ndarray when doing a regression, since I get the same result for intercept and coef when I do not convert it?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
%matplotlib inline

# import data and create dataframe

!wget -O FuelConsumption.csv https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses-data/CognitiveClass/ML0101ENv3/labs/FuelConsumptionCo2.csv    

df = pd.read_csv("FuelConsumption.csv")
cdf = df[['ENGINESIZE','CYLINDERS','FUELCONSUMPTION_COMB','CO2EMISSIONS']]

# Split train/ test data

msk = np.random.rand(len(df)) < 0.8 
train = cdf[msk] 
test = cdf[~msk] 

# Modeling

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

train_x = np.asanyarray(train[['ENGINESIZE']])
train_y = np.asanyarray(train[['CO2EMISSIONS']])

**# if I use the dataframe, train[['ENGINESIZE']] for 'x', and train[['CO2EMISSIONS']] for 'y' 
below, I get the same result**

regr.fit (train_x, train_y) 

# The coefficients
print ('Coefficients: ', regr.coef_)
print ('Intercept: ',regr.intercept_)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: a dataframe is just an enhanced ndarray, it uses ndarray underneath. The only reason would be speed and optimisation i see no other reason to use ndarray instead of dataframe. Lest you avoid one extra layer of complexity

Answer (score 1):

So `df` is the loaded dataframe, `cdf` is another frame with selected columns, and `train` is selected rows.

`train[['ENGINESIZE']]` is a 1 column dataframe (I believe `train['ENGINESIZE']` would be a pandas Series).

I believe the preferred syntax for getting an array from the dataframe is:

```
 train[['ENGINESIZE']].values          # or
 train[['ENGINESIZE']].to_numpy()
```

though

```
 np.asanyarray(train[['ENGINESIZE']])
```

is supposed to do the same thing.

Digging down through the `regr.fit` code I see that it calls `sklearn.utils.check_X_y` which in turn calls `sklearn.tils.check_array`.  That takes care of converting the inputs to numpy arrays, with some awareness of pandas dataframe peculiarities (such as multiple dtypes).

So it appears that if `fit` accepts your dataframes, you don't need to convert them ahead of time.  But if you can get a nice array from the dataframe, there's no harm in do that either.  Either way the fit is done with arrays, derived from the dataframe.